# Finding a limit using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (e^x+x)^{4/x}.$$
Use L'Hospital's rule if appropriate. If there is a more elementary method, consider using it.

Comment: Why the tag _multivariable calculus_? This is calculus of one variable.

Comment: @Bye_World Because they're taught in the same course?

Comment: the limit can be evaluated without using l'hospital rule. for $x \to \infty, e^x$ dominates $x,$ so throw the $x$ away. now you are left with $(e^x)^{4/x} = e^4.$

Comment: Note that it's "L'Hopital," or if you're feeling fancy, "L'Hôpital."

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** For a more elementary method, I suggest Squeezing. Note that for positive $x$ we have
$$e^x\lt e^x+x\lt 2e^x$$

Comment: With large enough $x$, you can replace that $2$ with any $c>1$, right?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Yes, but that is not needed fro the calculation, since $2^{4/x}$ has limit $1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (e^x +x)^{4/x}=\exp{\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{4\ln(e^x +x)}{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You could take logs, e.g. denoting your limit by $\ell$ we have

$$\log\ell = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4\log(e^x+x)}{x}.$$

Using L'Hopital's rule this gives

$$\log\ell = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4 \left(e^x+1\right)}{x+e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4 \left(e^x+x\right)}{x+e^x}+\frac{4 \left(1-x\right)}{x+e^x}.$$ But this is just $$4+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4 \left(1-x\right)}{x+e^x}=4.$$

Hence, $$\ell = e^4.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let:

$$y = \lim_{x\to\infty} (e^x+x)^{4/x}$$

Then,

$$\ln y = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{4}{x}\ln(e^x+x)$$

Direct substitution yields $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Using L'Hosptial's Rule:

$$\ln y = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{4}{x}\ln(e^x+x) = \frac{\frac{4(e^x+1)}{e^x+x}}{1} = \frac{4(e^x+1)}{e^x+x} = \frac{4e^x}{e^x+1} = \frac{4e^x}{e^x} = 4$$

So, $\ln y = 4$, and $y = e^4$

Note that multiple dervatives were taken since the direct substitution yielded $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: Could you please explain how you got the step ((4(e^x +1))/(e^x+x))/1

Comment: The rule tells its that if we are given an indeterminate form then we must take the derivative of the numerator and denominator

Comment: @Nansh He left off the $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ in each of the 5 rightmost equalities in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $e^x$ dominates on $x$, therefore a good idea is to factor it out

$$( x + e^x)^{4/x}=( e^x)^{4/x}\left( \frac x { e^x}+1\right)^{4/x}$$

then $( e^x)^{4/x}$ looks very simple and what about the form $1^0$? is it indeterminate?